# Is it possible to access a Kotlin typealias from Java?

Tags: java, kotlin, kotlin-interop

Suppose I have a Kotlin 1.1 `typealias` for a Kotlin function type like this

```
typealias Consumer<T> = (T) -> Unit
```

I can access this from Java as

```
import kotlin.Unit;
import kotlin.jvm.functions.Function1;

Function1<? super T, Unit> action = ...
```

Is it somehow possible to access the Kotlin `Function1` interface from Java under its Kotlin typealias name (i.e., `Consumer`)?

Answer (score 30, accepted):

From the [KEEP proposal](https://github.com/Kotlin/KEEP/blob/master/proposals/type-aliases.md) for type aliases:

> NB Java has no concept of "type aliases" and can't see them in class member signatures.

So no, you can't use typealiases from Java, you'll just see the actual types of any parameter or variable that has a typealias'd type in Kotlin.