# Translate Kotlin interface to Java

Tags: java, android, kotlin

I am using this library which is a CalendarView. https://github.com/kizitonwose/CalendarView

In the sample code there is the following code which attaches a Scroll Listener to the CalendarView

```
 calendarView.monthScrollListener = { // etc}
```

I am unsure how to translate this to Java, I try the following but the "MonthScrollListener" class is nowhere to be found, its like it want some other type but I cannot find the type. Everything else has worked so far when translating the Kotlin to Java but I cannot see how this might work

```
mBinding.calendarView.setMonthScrollListener(new MonthScrollListener(){ // etc});
```

What should I pass into the setMonthScrollListener() method?

Edit: when I "ctrl click" on the setMonthScrollListener() it takes me into the CalendarView class and there is the following line:

```
  public final var monthScrollListener: com.kizitonwose.calendarview.ui.MonthScrollListener? /* = ((com.kizitonwose.calendarview.model.CalendarMonth) -> kotlin.Unit)? */ /* compiled code */
```

So I try explicitly referencing the MonthScrollListener but everything is resolved up to the MonthScrollListener, which isnt available...

[image]

Comment: I tried this however it "cannot resolve symbol MonthScrollListener".

Comment: That's because `MonthScrollListener` isn't an actual type, it's an alias, which can be found [here](https://github.com/kizitonwose/CalendarView/blob/e2efbe7da6b890acb97933b982f6d4c8a512ba05/library/src/main/java/com/kizitonwose/calendarview/ui/Types.kt#L19).

Comment: Yes I came across that whilst digging around, how am I supposed to use that in Java? Is it possible?

Comment: @brux [Apparently not](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46552242/is-it-possible-to-access-a-kotlin-typealias-from-java).

Comment: Aye, what a shame :(

Answer (score 1):

[`typealias`](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/type-aliases.html) is not visible in Java, but given the example you're talking about is:

```
typealias MonthScrollListener = (CalendarMonth) -> Unit
```

Then in Java world it should be similar to single method interface like (more about it below):

```
import kotlin.Unit;
interface MonthScrollListener {
  Unit whatever(CalendarMonth cm);
}
```

It could be `void` because this is what `Unit` means in Kotlin but you know - life.

So passing Lambda in that method which expects listener should look like:

```java
whatever.setMonthScrollListener((CalendarMonth cm) -> {
  // w00t
  return kotlin.Unit.INSTANCE;
});
```

I've basically ended up writing the same approach as suggested by @MishaAkopov

**Edit (after reading about it):**

But what type is it actually? It appears that Kotlin standard library has a [bunch of interfaces](https://github.com/JetBrains/kotlin/blob/master/spec-docs/function-types.md#function0-function1--types) like `Function0<R>` and `Function2<P1,P2,R>` that have one method `invoke`. So if you'd need to use above Kotlin code in previous Java versions it would instead look like:

```java
Function1<CalendarMonth, Unit> listener = new Function1<CalendarMonth, Unit>() {
  @Override
  public Unit invoke(CalendarMonth cm) {
    // Do something with calendar month
    return kotlin.Unit.INSTANCE;
  }
}
whatever.setMonthScrollListener(listener);
```